# Setting Background Color on a Title with Unknown Size

Tags: html, css

I have an html template that displays `post.title`, inputted by the user.

```
 <section id="home" class="">
    <h1 class="main-heading"><%= @post.title %></h1>
  </section>
```

The user's title is of unknown length. It could be (for example) 5, 20 or 100 characters.

I want to put an low-opacity black background behind the text, to help the reader distinguish the title:

```
.main-heading {
    /*TEXT ON MAIN PIC*/
  height: 20%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 95px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.2);
}
```

I can adjust height and width for a predictable title, but don't know how to apply these values for a title that will vary in size.

Comment: Are you able to use [`text-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow)?

Comment: Yes I am, but that's best for styling the letters. I'd prefer a box around the title, similar to this codepen: https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/xyufl

Comment: add a background-color and use `display: inline[-block]` to make it not take up the whole screen width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to add a wrapper that you can then style.

```css
.main-heading {
    /*TEXT ON MAIN PIC*/
  height: 20%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 95px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(100,100,100,0.6);
}

.background {
  background-color: rgba(10,10,10,0.2);
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="">
    <h1 class="main-heading">
        <span class="background">
            foobar
        </span>
    </h1>
</section>
```

I think this is what you're looking for, and it's pretty simple as well. Naturally, you can set `display: inline-block` and add in padding/margin at will.

Comment: That makes sense. I guessed a fluid wrapper was a solution. I'll accept when I get it to work. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure how else to go about it, and it's minimal added complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap te `<%= @post.title %>` into a `span`(inside of the `h1`), apply your styling to that span and also add `display: inline-block` to it:

```css
.main-heading>span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 9px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.6);
  background-color: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<section id="home" class="">
  <h1 class="main-heading"><span><%= @post.title %></span></h1>
</section>
```

Comment: A separate wrapper, similar to jhpratt's answer. Thanks, clearer now.